# React-Native: Failed prop type: style may be false but not true

Tags: react-native

while programming with react-native I encountered this strange error.

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYrLg.jpg)

It does not make any sense to me. 
I copied the "first setup" (welcome to react! to get...) of react-native  and put it behind a login page. I linked both of them using react-native-router-flux.

I didn't change anything of the code from first setup, I just called it from another scene.

I don't understand how an error can emerge when I  applied no direct changes to the "first setup " scene.

Edit:

The error happened emerged after displaying scene2.

Rooter that connects both scenes:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    import Scene2 from './components/Scene2';
    import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

    const RouterComponent = () => {
      return (
        <Router sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 65 }} >

          <Scene key="auth">
            <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
          </Scene>

          <Scene key="main" style>
            <Scene
            key="ingredient"
            component={Scene2}
          //  hideNavBar={true}
            />
          </Scene>

        </Router>
      );
    };

export default RouterComponent;
```

Scene 1:

The LoginScrenn

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button, Spinner } from './common';


class LoginForm extends Component {
  onEmailChange(text) {
    this.props.emailChanged(text);
  }

  onPasswordChange(text) {
    this.props.passwordChanged(text);
  }

 onButtonPress() {
   const { email, password } = this.props;

   this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
 }
  renderButton() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
      return <Spinner size="large" />;
    }

    return (
      <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
        Confirm
      </Button>
    );
  }

  render() {
  return (
  <Card>
    <CardSection>
      <Input
        label="Email:"
        placeholder="email@gmail.com"
        onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.props.email}
      />
    </CardSection>

    <CardSection>
      <Input
        secureTextEntry
        label="Passwort:"
        placeholder="*******"
        onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.props.password}

      />
    </CardSection>

    <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
      {this.props.error}
    </Text>
    <CardSection>
      {this.renderButton()}
    </CardSection>

      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red',
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
  const { email, password, error, loading } = auth;

  return { email, password, error, loading
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
   emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser
})(LoginForm);
```

Scene 2:
   I didn't change anything in the view tag, but when I enter the scene which is display the code I get the error I mentioned above.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Scene2: extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Thank you in advance,
Michael

Comment: This just means there's some variable that won't ever be true. It can be either false or undefined. Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have an extra "style" in the router part of your code.

You have...

> ```
> <Scene key="main" style>
> ```

It should be

> ```
> <Scene key="main">
> ```

Comment: Oh you are right, I corrected it and the error is gone now. thank you